# Concatenate Julia DataFrames adding a categorical column

Tags: dataframe, julia

Say I have the following

```
a = DataFrame(x = [1,2,3,4], y = [10,20,30,40])
b = DataFrame(x = [1,2,3,4], y = [50,60,70,80])
```

is there a way of getting `[a;b]` with an additional categorical column to obtain something like the following?

```
8×3 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ x │ y  │ c │
├─────┼───┼────┼───┤
│ 1   │ 1 │ 10 │ 1 │
│ 2   │ 2 │ 20 │ 1 │
│ 3   │ 3 │ 30 │ 1 │
│ 4   │ 4 │ 40 │ 1 │
│ 5   │ 1 │ 50 │ 2 │
│ 6   │ 2 │ 60 │ 2 │
│ 7   │ 3 │ 70 │ 2 │
│ 8   │ 4 │ 80 │ 2 │
```

For two dataframes, something like

```
using DataFramesMeta
[@transform(a, c = 1); @transform(b, c = 2)]
```

works, but what if I have more than a few `DataFrame`s?

Comment: Do you mean something like this`l = [a,b]; vcat([transform(x,c=i) for (i,x) in enumerate(l)])` ?

Comment: That could work. Care to make it an answer so I can accept it? :)

Comment: Maybe somebody could find better solution without creating array as vcat's parameter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `enumerate` if you like to create result from array of `DataFrame`s. For example:

```
l = [a,b]
vcat([transform(x,c=i) for (i,x) in enumerate(l)])
```